# Send requests with Python (intercepted with Burp)

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-post, burp

I'm having trouble understanding requests.
Let's say I have this request:

```
POST /user/follow HTTP/1.1
Host: www.website.com
User-Agent: some user agent
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Referer: https://www.website.com/users/12345/profile
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
X-CSRF-TOKEN: Ab1/2cde3fGH
Content-Length: 27
Cookie: some-cookie=;
DNT: 1
Connection: close

{"targetUser":"12345"}
```

How am I supposed to use this information to send a valid request using python?
What I found is not really helpful. I need someone to show me an example with the data I gave you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```
import requests
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "some user agent",
    "Content-Length": 27
    # you get the point
     }
data = {
    "targetUser" : "12345"
    }
url = "www.website.com/user/follow"
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers,data=data)
```

Yes, you would use cookies to log in. Cookies are a part of the headers.

Comment: So, Content-Length can't be a string? ("27")

Comment: I would keep it as integer, but a string is fine.

Comment: A python error just told me that it has to be a string. Anyways, it seems like the website has some cookies that store some stuff like time/date and session tokens, most likely to prevent botting... this is gonna be tough.

Comment: You guys have fun while I try to figure out how to get through "XSRF Token Validation". By the way, I don't know which answer to accept. Can't both.

Comment: Oops, sorry for my mistake. I recently had a problem with CSRF tokens. I didn't continue what I was working on, but I think it could be bypassed with a session. I'm not sure how that works with requests, but at least it's possible.

Comment: I can get the token through console, put it in Burp's repeater and send the request. It worked. Now I gotta make that work with my script.

Comment: I need your help again. When I send the request with burp it works just fine, but when I send it with python I get back this response: {"isValid":false,"data":null,"error":""}

Comment: Will you just make a new question for this and link me to it? I can try to help but there's definitely people who know more than I. Include more details if you do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311053/strange-error-response-requests

Answer (score 2):

I will not write poems i just give you some exapmle code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Referer": "SOMETHING",
    "Cookie": "SOMETHING",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
data = "SOME DATA"
url = "https://example.com/something"

request = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

In headers you set needed header etc. you got it i think ;)

Comment: Thanks, but where should the last line - {"targetUser":"12345"} go in my case? It seems to be different from the rest.

Comment: In your case you should change "SOME DATA" to " {"targetUser":"12345"} ".
In data variable you should insert your data :)

Answer (score -2):

This Burp extension may help: [Copy As Python-Requests](https://portswigger.net/bappstore/b324647b6efa4b6a8f346389730df160)

It can copy selected request(s) as Python-Requests invocations.

In your case, after copying as Python-Requests, you get:

```py
import requests

burp0_url = "http://www.website.com:80/user/follow"
burp0_cookies = {"some-cookie": ""}
burp0_headers = {"User-Agent": "some user agent", "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Accept-Language": "pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3", "Referer": "https://www.website.com/users/12345/profile", "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8", "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "Ab1/2cde3fGH", "DNT": "1", "Connection": "close"}
burp0_json={"targetUser": "12345"}
requests.post(burp0_url, headers=burp0_headers, cookies=burp0_cookies, json=burp0_json)
```