# Strange error response - requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-post

Updated code - I'm using this code to send the request:

```
headers = {
"Host": "www.roblox.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
"Accept-Language": "en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
"Referer": "https://www.roblox.com/users/12345/profile",
"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
"X-CSRF-TOKEN": "some-xsrf-token",
"Content-Length": "27",
"DNT": "1",
"Connection": "close"
}
data = {"targetUserId":"56789"}
url = "http://www.roblox.com/user/follow"

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, cookies={"name":"value"})
```

Response (using r.text):

```
{"isValid":false,"data":null,"error":""}
```

The request itself is valid, I sent it using burp and it worked:

```
POST /user/follow HTTP/1.1
Host: www.roblox.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Referer: https://www.roblox.com/users/12345/profile
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
X-CSRF-TOKEN: Ab1/2cde3fGH
Content-Length: 27
Cookie: some-cookie=;
DNT: 1
Connection: close

{"targetUser":"56789"}
```

Comment: When I asked for more info, I expected the website you're using so I can test it myself. Plz add that to question?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That is the opposite of what a lot of places say. I am aware it is possible to send cookies the way you mention, but this should work, too.

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape Changed links to real website.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it. ROBLOX? Recently they've been stepping up security with capchas.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I think you might be right - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library

Comment: @David http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467114/how-are-cookies-passed-in-the-http-protocol tho??  Check my answer.

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape My bad, `Cookie` header should work as well but not sure if the OP had used the correct format.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary this was something I was thinking about on OP's question made yesterday about this, that it needed to be a dictionary.

Comment: With headers :  `"Cookie":  "name1=value1; name2=value2"`  should be the format.

Comment: That **is** the format.

Comment: Did you include all of them?

Comment: With headers, yes, but when I did it with the dictionary, I only included the most important one. However, I think I would get a different error-response if it was about not enough cookies.

Comment: If you use the request.post(cookies=) thing, you can make cookies a dictionary instead of "name1=value1; name2=value2".

Comment: Then the problem is unrelated to how you are sending cookies, i expect.

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape I did, and I got the same response as in original post.

Comment: What error number did you get? Was it 403?

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape As I wrote in the original post, full response (using r.text):
`{"isValid":false,"data":null,"error":""}`

Comment: i think @apoorlydrawnape means the http status : `r.status_code`

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape oh. 200.

Comment: So no error. This is more about ROBLOX than http requests in that case.

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape But it works in burp suite, so?...

Comment: Make sure that you post __all__ your headers and __all__ your cookies properly

Comment: If it works in Burp but not Python, there's a difference. Maybe you are not sending all cookies.

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape I put all cookies in the dictionary and sent them. Exact same response.

Comment: Ok. See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it works in Burp but not in Python requests, get a packet sniffer (Wireshark is the simplest IMO) and look to see the difference in the packet sent by Burp that works and the one sent from Python that does not work. I am suspecting that the problem is that the website is HTTPS but you are using http://www.roblox.com . Do try https://www.roblox.com , but I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: Wireshark hurts my brain. The documentation is not really helpful. Also, I tried with both http and https, and nothing changed.